# how to use image url variable inside another javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, html

could any one tell me how to use myVariable and myVariable2 correctly inside javascript variable called siteContents2? at this moment my code does not display image thumb and its name.

```
 var siteContents2=""
            +"<li>"
            +"<img src=""+myVariable2+"" width=\"180\" height=\"148\""
            +"alt=\"'+myVariable+'\" class=\"png\">"
            +"<a href=\"'+myVariable+'"  class=\"corners\">&nbsp;<\/a>"
            +""
            +"    "
            +"        "
            +"            "
            +"<div class=\"thumbnail_label\">mango<\/div>"
            +"            "
            +"        "
            +"    "
            +""
            +"<div class=\"details\">"
            +"<div class=\"title\">"
            +"      <a  href="
            +"      \"'+myVariable+'">"+myVariable+"<\/a>"
            +"      <span class=\"season\">2<\/span>"
            +"    <\/div>"
            +"    <ul class=\"subject\">"
            +"      <li>mango sesaon<\/li>"
            +"    <\/ul>"
            +"    <ul class=\"sub-info\">"
            +"      <li class=\"location\">us<\/li>"
            +"      <li class=\"price\">2 dollar<\/li>"
            +"    <\/ul>"
            +"  <\/div>"
            +"<\/li>";

         $('#myDiv').append(siteContents2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape all double quotes and use this code to use a variable:

```
var str = "Text text "+variable_name+" continuing text";
```

**Only** variables are wrapped like `"+variable+"`.

If you have a lot of double quotes, you can use a single quote to around your variable content, like this:

```
var str = '<div class="test">'+variable_name+'</div>';
```

If you have a single quote in that example, you should escape it like `\'`. Double quotes don't need to be escaped then.

Answer (score 1):

```
var siteContents2=""
            +"<li>"
            +"<img src='"  + myVariable2 + "' width=\"180\" height=\"148\""
            +"alt='" + myVariable + "' class=\"png\">"
            +"<a href='" +myVariable+ "'  class=\"corners\">&nbsp;<\/a>"
            +""
            +"    "
            +"        "
            +"            "
            +"<div class=\"thumbnail_label\">mango<\/div>"
            +"            "
            +"        "
            +"    "
            +""
            +"<div class=\"details\">"
            +"<div class=\"title\">"
            +"      <a  href="
            +"      '" + myVariable + "'>"+myVariable+"<\/a>"
            +"      <span class=\"season\">2<\/span>"
            +"    <\/div>"
            +"    <ul class=\"subject\">"
            +"      <li>mango sesaon<\/li>"
            +"    <\/ul>"
            +"    <ul class=\"sub-info\">"
            +"      <li class=\"location\">us<\/li>"
            +"      <li class=\"price\">2 dollar<\/li>"
            +"    <\/ul>"
            +"  <\/div>"
            +"<\/li>";
```